# SAP pdf exporting

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have the code below that I was using to export PDF from SAP. It was working on previous SAP version, but now it gets "runtime error 438, object doesn't support this property or method" on Browserhandle.locationURL.

Could you please give me a hint what should I change?

```
Call SAPopen(SystemName, SystemID, TransID)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

For i = 6 To lastInv

    invRef = Cells(i, 2)
    invName = Cells(i, 3)
    fileName = fPath & invName & ".pdf"
    If FileExists(fileName) = True Then fileName = fPath & invName & "i" & ".pdf"

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").Text = invRef
    session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[11]").Select
    
    If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[0]" Then
        Message = "No output exists"
        GoTo WriteMsg
    End If
    
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLVMSGTABCONTROL").getAbsoluteRow(0).Selected = True
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[37]").press
    
    If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
        Message = "No output could be opened"
        GoTo WriteMsg
    End If
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "pdf!"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    
    pdfLocL = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlHTML/shellcont/shell").Browserhandle.locationURL
    pdfLocStart = InStr(pdfLocL, "C:")
    pdfLocS = Mid(pdfLocL, pdfLocStart, 9999)
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FSO.copyfile pdfLocS, fileName
    
    If FileExists(fileName) = True Then Message = "Invoice saved" Else Message = "Invoice not saved"
    
    session.findById("wnd[1]").Close
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]").Close
    Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: So, you are talking about exporting a PDF from the `GuiHtmlViewer` object. Since SAP GUI 7.70, you have the possibility between the old MS IE and the newest Edge engines. Which SAP GUI version are you using, and if it's SAP GUI 7.70 which engine is configured?

Comment: Hi Sandra, yes 7.70 and changing it back to MS IE solved the issue. Thank you! :)

Comment: Could you please write an answer so I can close the question? I don't want to delete, someone else may find it helpful and I can mark my own answer as solution in only 2 days.

Comment: I didn't know, I was just mentioning a few facts. Great that it solved, and I voted for your answer. You can also mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing browser control back to Internet Explorer.